# Form is not being submit while fetch data using ajax search

Tags: php, mysql

I created a search which live search database data. I've shown data in tabular form and create a form inside this table. In this form, i need a button for form submission. The problem is, this button cannot submit form. This form is created in Fetch.php file as you can see this line of code `<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover"></td>`. Search is working fine but form is not submitting.

The Fetch.php code is,

```
    <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stolen_cars");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM record 
  WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR model LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR registration_no LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR chassis_no LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR color LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR city LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR district LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM record ORDER BY id
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Model</th>
     <th>Reg.#</th>
     <th>Chassis#</th>
     <th>Engine#</th>
     <th>Color</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Distt.</th>
     <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 $output .= '<form method="post" action="index.php" class=text-center>' ;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '

   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["model"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["registration_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["chassis_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["engine_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["color"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["city"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["district"].'</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover"></td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
$output .= '</form>';
 echo $output;
 }

else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

Search:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Search</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by name, model, registeration#, chassis# etc." class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to submit the form using ajax?

Comment: no, need to sumbit form using PHP

Comment: $output .= 'something'; means that rows of data will be collected and then displayed in a tabular arrangement. $output must be initialized first before being used by declaring it as $output = ''; That said, you need to rewrite your code

Comment: class attribute is not defined properly in your form tag i guess thats why it is not working. It should be defined like this `class="classname"`

Comment: @Exterminator still not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you break the html since the while loop adds form tags in each iteration 
furthermore, the all relevant inputs should be inside the form

So 1st of all, the form should move out of the table
the

```
<th>action</th>
```

should be removed

And the while loop should remove the form tags:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '

   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["model"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["registration_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["chassis_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["engine_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["color"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["city"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["district"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
$output .=' </table>' ;
```

2nd of all, the submission shohld be with the text:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" class=text-center>' ;
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by name, model, registeration#, chassis# etc." class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover">
</form>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i've update question according to your suggusted code but still not work

Comment: There's a bit of fixing I need to do, but the form is unclear, where is the input names "query"?

Comment: please see into <script> tag

Comment: you're giving wrong answer. I need <th>action</th> . why i remove this

Comment: the text input and tge submit should be together, not half way in and out of a table...

Comment: you're understand wrong. <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover"> is a part of form not search

Comment: then I don't get something else - how does the ajax should update the page? ajax is asynchronous by definition... you can't use ajax to call back the entire page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stolen_cars");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM record 
  WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR model LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR registration_no LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR chassis_no LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR color LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR city LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR district LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM record ORDER BY id
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  ?>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Reg.#</th>
      <th>Chassis#</th>
      <th>Engine#</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Distt.</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

  <?php
  foreach ($result as $row) { 

            echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["model"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["registration_no"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["chassis_no"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["engine_no"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["color"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["city"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row["district"]."</td>";
               echo "<td>
                  <form method=post><input class='btn btn-light' type='submit' name='btn_delete' value='Delete'></form>
                </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
           }
           ?>

  </table>
  <?php
 }

else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```